# AppState always returns background as currentState for Android in react-native

Tags: react-native

The `react-native` [AppState](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html) API tell the current state of the app that can be used while handling local/remote notification. It provides correct application state for iOS but for Android, I always get the `AppState.currentState` as `background`.

Is this because of the way the notifications are handled by Android?

Is there another way of figuring out whether the notification is received when the app is in foreground vs background?

Comment: I am able to get `active` and `background` from AppState. `inactive` however does not work as it does on iOS for some reason. What are you using for push notifications? Firebase, GCM etc

Comment: The issue was using the AppState within the local/remote notifications for Android. I have been using the package `react-native-push-notification` to handle local/remote notifications within my app and the AppState doesn't behave as it does for iOS in the notification handlers.

Comment: its hard to comment so please share code snippet; in meantime, until u subscribe to appState event value of AppState.currentState will unchanged. here is how you subscribe to listen changes 
```
    AppState.addEventListener(
      'change', 
      (nextAppState) => { console.log("new app state is: ", nextAppState )}
    )
```

Comment: @PramendraGupta I have already mentioned in my comment the reason behind getting the current state as background. I will close the question. Thanks!